Eigenvalues of superoperators and their Choi matrices
Denote by $E_{i,j}$ the matrix of which only the $(i,j)$th entry is $1$ and all the others are $0$. It is well known that $\Phi$ is a completely-positive and trace-preserving (CPTP) map if and only if the corresponding Choi matrix $C_\Phi:=\sum_{i,j} E_{i,j}\otimes \Phi(E_{i,j})$ is positive semi-definite (PSD) and $(\operatorname{id}\otimes\operatorname{Tr})\cdot(C_\Phi)=\operatorname{id}$. It seems that their spectrums have some kind of relationship with each other, is it true? Specifically speaking, what is the relationship between the eigenvalues of $\Phi$ and $C_\Phi$?
Thank you so much!

Update: Thanks @Martin Argerami for correcting me about the equivalence between a CPTP map $\Phi$ and the properties of its Choi matrix $C_\Phi$, which has been fixed above. Also thanks @glS for the related source. Now I see the eigenvalues of $C_\Phi$ are more about (the square of) the Frobenius norm of the Kraus operators of $\Phi$, owing to the use of spectral decomposition elucidated in a comment under the accepted answer on https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/21155/55.

related on qc.SE: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/21155/55

Thanks @glS. There might be another related post on qc.SE: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6982

A quick answer, while we wait for a better one.
First, the positivity of the Choi matrix cannot tell you anything regarding whether $\Phi$ is trace-preserving or not; for if you multiply $\Phi$ by a positive scalar the positivity of the Choi matrix is not affected.
As for eigenvalues, here is a trivial example that shows that there doesn't seem to be much of a relationship. Let $\Phi:M_2(\mathbb C)\to M_2(\mathbb C)$ be the identity map. Its Choi matrix is
$$
C=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Counting multiplicities, we have
$$
\sigma(\Phi)=\{1\},\qquad \sigma(C)=\{0,0,0,2\}.
$$
For a second example let $\Phi:M_4(\mathbb C)\to M_4(\mathbb C)$ be given by $\Phi(A)=VAV^*$, where $V$ is a unitary. Let us first look at the eigenvalues of $\Phi$. If $VAV^*=\lambda A$ for nonzero $A$, taking norm we get $|\lambda|=1$. Also, since the spectrum does not change under unitary conjugation, $\sigma(A)=\lambda\sigma(A)$. As this is a finite set, we get that $\lambda $ is a root of unity if $A$ has a nonzero eigenvalue. Since $V$ is unitarily diagonalizable, we may assume without loss of generality that it is diagonal. For a concrete example, let
$$
V=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&i &0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-i \end{bmatrix}.
$$
It is then straightforward to check that
$$
\sigma(\Phi)=\{1,i,-1,-i \},
$$
each with multiplicity 4. The 16 matrix units are eigenvectors. Meanwhile
$$
C=\sum_{k,j}E_{k,j}\otimes VE_{k,j}V^*
=V^{(4)}\,\Big(\sum_{k,j}E_{k,j}\otimes E_{k,j}\Big)\,(V^{(4)})^*.
$$
As unitary conjugation preserves the spectrum,
$$
\sigma(C)=\sigma\Big(\sum_{k,j}E_{k,j}\otimes E_{k,j}\Big)=\{0,4\},
$$
where $4$ has multiplicity 1 and $0$ has multiplicity 15.

I don't understand the first statement. The function between maps and Chois is linear. The Choi of $\lambda\Phi$ is $\lambda J$ if $J$ is the Choi of $\Phi$. So of course you can tell whether a map is trace-preserving from the Choi, just looking at (one of) its partial trace(s)

I was addressing the statement by OP, that wrote the incorrect statement "$\Phi$ is CPTP if and only if $C_\Phi$ is positive definite".

Thanks for your detailed answer so much! I was not aware of my incorrectness and what you posted was exactly what I wanted to learn!
